# Saving Program/Game Data to readable text file in ActionScript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am trying to create a multiple choice trivia game using Flash and AS3. I would like to be able to have different sets of questions by category along with settings specific to each set, and have all this data saved to a readable text file. I have already used `SharedObject` but I would like to be able to create "Question Sets" for other computers? Does anyone have a idea of what type of code I should use?

I need to be able to do the following:

-Create the file (SetOne.txt)

-Save data to the file

-Append the data in the file

Thank You

Comment: the answer will depends on what type of project this is, AIR, Web, etc?

Comment: Desktop only, I would like it to be an SWF or maybe a .exe Projector. I woul like to stay away from using AIR or FLEX.

Comment: to put it simply, if it's a swf or projector then keep using sharedobject cos there's no other solution besides hacks. If it's a school project then that's good enough. If it's supposed to be a professional project then be a professional and use AIR.

Comment: If you plan to run your app on several computers with different settings, consider running a client-server architecture, and use XML or JSON payload with questions retrieved form the server to be parsed on the client. Your set of question sets can then be a database, a set of files (XML/JSON even, without any need of transcoding them on the server) or a single file depending on your needs.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if you want to do this then I think it will have to be an Air app, you say you want it to be a Desktop app anyway so you can choose to compile to a Desktop Air app which is what you want, get icons and everything but most importantly you can use File() / FileReference() to write to files and call commands, if you're fixed on not using Air then I can't help with the saving of a txt file but if you would consider it then I can push you in the right direction to get started with some code.

Also if you plan to connect multiple computers to access these answers then you should really be using a database and maybe PHP, seems like your requirements would be easy to learn but I hate working with databases so someone else can help with that.